# after flask app launched, how can I let the database updating function keep running backend

Tags: python, flask, web, flask-sqlalchemy

I use scheduler to call a function - "DataBaseUpdate" before app.run(),there is a "While True" loop inside.
My design was like I have a function to keep updating database in app.py , then app shows what in database.

But it seems like after flask app was launched, my app no longer running in backend. Just like it run though one time then done. How can I let my program keep running backend and updating database?

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    with app.app_context():
        db.create_all() # <--- create db object.
    start = datetime.date.today()+ datetime.timedelta(days=1)  #set start and end time
    end= start + datetime.timedelta(days=10)

    scheduler = BackgroundScheduler()
    scheduler.add_job(DataBaseUpdate, 'interval', seconds=30)
    scheduler.start()

    port = int(os.environ.get('PORT', 5000))
    app.run(debug=True, host='0.0.0.0', port=port)
```

Comment: So I assume there are processes outside of your webserver that update values in the database? Or why do you want to update it?

Comment: @Lenntror thx for response. I want the app scrap some webpages and save to a backend database. Then frontend can show the database results.But it seems like if I put scheduler in "if __name__ == "__main__":" it just run once. So the "DataBaseUpdate" didn't run after deployment. So I am confused. how should I design and let a process keep running after deployment.

Comment: So do I understand you correctly: You want the webapp programmed with flask and then you want another service to occasionally scrape some websites and safe the results to the database?

Comment: @Lenntror yes. I am not sure if the service function should be put in if __name__ == "__main__": or somewhere

Answer (score 0):

Eventually I found this below code works. However, I don't know why I don't get the result until first timer <=> 1hr reached.

```
scheduler = BackgroundScheduler()
scheduler.add_job(func=NA1, trigger="interval", hours=1)
scheduler.start()



if __name__ == "__main__":
    with app.app_context():
        db.create_all() # <--- create db object.
    #thread1 = threading.Thread(target=NA1,name='NAThread')
    #thread1.start()
    #scheduler.start()
    port = int(os.environ.get('PORT', 5000))
    app.run(debug=True, host='0.0.0.0', port=port)
```